# Why isn't my WKWebView resizing properly inside my subview?

Tags: swift, resize, subview

I am creating a minimal WebKit browser for a Mac OS App using the following Swift code to load the new WKWebView into an Custom View Object.

When I run the App the web page loads correctly and fills the window, however if the window is resized the subview does not resize with the window.

Any Help would be most appreciated.

```
import Cocoa 
import WebKit
import AppKit

@NSApplicationMain class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

@IBOutlet weak var customView: NSView!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    var url = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL:url!)
    var theWebView:WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: customView.bounds)
    self.customView.autoresizingMask = NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewWidthSizable | NSAutoresizingMaskOptions.ViewHeightSizable
    self.customView.addSubview(theWebView)
    theWebView.loadRequest(request)
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
}
```

Comment: This should work IF the customView is resizable with the window. You do not show how that is constrained or linked, presumably it's done in IB.